# Match and Display Value from JSON in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

**JSON response is as follows:**

```
{"approvals": 
    [
         {"approval":
            {
               "id":"0121920",
               "key":"T100",
               "value":"Ben Tsu"
            }
         },
         {"approval":
            {
               "id":"",
               "key":"T1000",
               "value":"Amy Dong"
            }
         }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to loop through all properties in the JSON file and match the value of the "key" property passed in as the parameter.

So, to the plugin I'm passing a value "T1000". If this value exists as an approval "key" value in the JSON file, I want to display the corresponding approval "value" (in this case Amy Dong).

I'm passing inputFieldDefaultValue as a parameter to the plugin with the value being "T1000". Hence, o.inputFieldDefaultValue.

Here's my JQuery plugin code but it's only spitting out object Object, object Object. So, if I have 5 "approval", this code spits out object Object 5 times.

```
$.each(response.approvals, function(index, approvals){ 
    if(approvals.approval.key == o.inputFieldDefaultValue){ 
         approvals.approval.value; 
    } 
});
```

If I do

```
$.each(response.approvals, function(index, approvals){ 
    if(approvals.approval.key == o.inputFieldDefaultValue){ 
         alert(approvals.approval.value); 
    } 
});
```

it alerts the corresponding value (Amy Dong) but it still writes object Object (as many times as the properties in the JSON response).

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I'm confused.  The line `approvals.approval.value;` does nothing.  Where is `object Object` being displayed?

Comment: Typo in your code?  Shouldn't you be checking `this`?  Ie, `this.approval.key` and `this.approval.value`?

Comment: `approvals` is `this` in this context, I believe. See the parameters of the function.

Comment: `it still writes object Object...`. Where does it write that?

Comment: @gilly3 approvals should work because it is the second param in the callback function which holds the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, and all you need is return the `value`, you need something like that:

```
var result = null;
$.each(response.approvals, function(index, approvals){ 
    if(approvals.approval.key == o.inputFieldDefaultValue){ 
         result = approvals.approval.value; 
    } 
});
return result;
```

I assumed this code is inside some function which is to return the correct value.